# Primefaces selectOneButton filter outside datatable

Tags: java, primefaces

I am trying to place a selectOneButton menu outside of my datatable and have it force the filter (as if the filter was a facet header, like the demo)

Essentially:

1. Select a value (true/false/null for both)
2. Pass that value to a JS function that will then force the filtering of the status column

The selectOneButton passes the value correctly

```
<script>
    function test(val){
        console.log(val);
        $("#allUsersForm\\:myTable\\:statusColumn\\:filter").val(val);
        $("#allUsersForm\\:myTable\\:statusColumn\\:filter").trigger('keyup');
    }
</script>

<h:form>
    <p:selectOneButton widgetVar="statusSelectWidget" 
        onchange="test(PF('statusSelectWidget').inputs.filter(':checked').val());">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="true" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="I" itemValue="false" />
    </p:selectOneButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="allUsersForm">  
    <p:dataTable 
        id="myTable"
        var="user" 
        widgetVar="userListWidget"
        filteredValue="#{myController.filteredUsers}"
        value="#{myController.allUsers}">

        <p:column id="statusColumn" style="width:10%;" headerText="Status" sortBy="#{user.isActive}"
            filterBy="#{user.isActive}" filterMatchMode="equals" 
            filterStyle="display:none;">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneButton style="display:none;" widgetVar="inTableStatusWidget" onchange="PF('userListWidget').filter()">
                    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="true" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="I" itemValue="false" />
                </p:selectOneButton>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Any ideas? I want to avoid having to handle filtering myself or making a call back to the backing bean if necessary.

Comment: Look at the omnifaces move component. But you can always add normal components outsode the datatable and use them in the load method of your lazy dafatable.

Comment: I've been able to create something like this in the past using a text field as a "proxy" - I enter the text, it enters it into the filter. I would prefer to keep it within the JSF/Primefaces world if I can (so I dont have to introduce anything else)